# Code improvement, Stock/price update from XLSX through API

Tags: java

I've written a program that I use every morning to update the stock and prices for my WooCommerce store. However, lately, it has gone from 5 minutes to over an hour to update. So now I would like to ask for possible code improvements, best practices, etc., as I'm only a self-taught developer, and it is always good to learn new stuff, better stuff.

So anyway, here it goes.

My program first takes an ID and SKU to load the products on my website. This file has two columns only.

```
    static void readCSVData() throws IOException {

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(CSV_FILE_PATH))) {
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                CSV_lookupTable.add(line.replaceAll("\"", "").split("\\|"));


            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //Some error logging
        }
    }
```

Then, I load in the XLSX file that the supplier provides using the following method:

```
static void XLSXReader() throws IOException {
        int regularPrice = 0;          //variable for storing the cell value
        int salePrice = 0;
        String SKU = null;
        String stock_quantity = null;

        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(XS_DATA_FILE_PATH);

            //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);


            for (int CSV_ROW_COUNTER = 1; CSV_ROW_COUNTER < CSV_lookupTable.size(); CSV_ROW_COUNTER++) {
                CSV_SKU = Arrays.toString(new String[]{CSV_lookupTable.get(CSV_ROW_COUNTER)[1]});
                CSV_SKU = CSV_SKU.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("]", "");
                CSV_ID = Arrays.toString(new String[]{CSV_lookupTable.get(CSV_ROW_COUNTER)[0]});
                CSV_ID = CSV_ID.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("]", "");


                //Iterate through each rows one by one
                for (int j = 2; j < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); j++) {

                    CellAddress SKU_ADDRESS = new CellAddress("B" + j);
                    Row ROW_SKU_ADDRESS = sheet.getRow(SKU_ADDRESS.getRow());
                    Cell CELL_SKU_ADDRESS = ROW_SKU_ADDRESS.getCell(SKU_ADDRESS.getColumn());
                    if (CELL_SKU_ADDRESS == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    SKU = "XS-" + CELL_SKU_ADDRESS.getRichStringCellValue().getString();


                    CellAddress PRICE_ADDRESS = new CellAddress("E" + j);
                    Row ROW_PRICE_ADDRESS = sheet.getRow(PRICE_ADDRESS.getRow());
                    Cell CELL_PRICE_ADDRESS = ROW_PRICE_ADDRESS.getCell(PRICE_ADDRESS.getColumn());
                    regularPrice = (int) CELL_PRICE_ADDRESS.getNumericCellValue();


                    CellAddress SALE_PRICE_ADDRESS = new CellAddress("F" + j);
                    Row ROW_SALE_PRICE_ADDRESS = sheet.getRow(SALE_PRICE_ADDRESS.getRow());
                    Cell CEll_SALE_PRICE_ADDRESS = ROW_SALE_PRICE_ADDRESS.getCell(SALE_PRICE_ADDRESS.getColumn());
                    salePrice = (int) CEll_SALE_PRICE_ADDRESS.getNumericCellValue();


                    CellAddress STOCK_QUANTITY_ADDRESS = new CellAddress("K" + j);
                    Row ROW_STOCK_QUANTITY_ADDRESS = sheet.getRow(STOCK_QUANTITY_ADDRESS.getRow());
                    Cell CELL_STOCK_QUANTITY = ROW_STOCK_QUANTITY_ADDRESS.getCell(STOCK_QUANTITY_ADDRESS.getColumn());
                    stock_quantity = CELL_STOCK_QUANTITY.getStringCellValue();


                    switch (stock_quantity) {
                        case "Tíz felett", "10 darab" -> stock_quantity = String.valueOf(10);
                        case "Nincs", "Beszállítótól megrendelve", "Bevételezés alatt", "Csak rendelésre", "Külső Raktárban", "Raktáron" -> stock_quantity = String.valueOf(0);
                        case "1 darab" -> stock_quantity = String.valueOf(1);
                        case "2 darab" -> stock_quantity = String.valueOf(2);
                        case "3 darab" -> stock_quantity = String.valueOf(3);
                        case "4 darab" -> stock_quantity = String.valueOf(4);
                        case "5 darab" -> stock_quantity = String.valueOf(5);
                        case "6 darab" -> stock_quantity = String.valueOf(6);
                        case "7 darab" -> stock_quantity = String.valueOf(7);
                        case "8 darab" -> stock_quantity = String.valueOf(8);
                        case "9 darab" -> stock_quantity = String.valueOf(9);
                    }


                    XSystemData[0] = SKU;
                    if (!CSV_SKU.equals(XSystemData[0])) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    XSystemData[1] = String.valueOf(roundPrice(regularPrice));
                    XSystemData[2] = String.valueOf(roundPrice(salePrice));
                    XSystemData[3] = stock_quantity;

                    updateStockAndPrices();


                }


                file.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The *updateStockAndPrices()* looks like this:

```
public static void updateStockAndPrices() throws IOException {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build();
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");


        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\r\n    \r\n    \"price\" : \"" + XSystemData[1] +
                "\",\r\n    \"regular_price\" : \"" + XSystemData[1] +
                "\",\r\n    \"sale_price\" : \"" + XSystemData[2] + "" +
                "\",\r\n    \"stock_quantity\" : \"" + XSystemData[3] + "\"\r\n}");
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://renton.hu/wp-json/wc/v3/products/" + CSV_ID)
                .header("Connection", "close")
                .method("PUT", body)
                .addHeader("Authorization", AuthorizationValue)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        response.close();
        System.out.println(XSystemData[0] + " frissítve");
    }
```

I'm looking to improve the above code, what I should or should not do/use, etc.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Which bit of it takes an hour to run?

Comment: The API update. That could be a server congestion issue, too.

Comment: Side note: `updateStockAndPrices();` seems to be using static data that's set by ´XLSXReader()`, right? That seems like some fragile design, did you consider passing the data via parameters or at least using instance variables to prevent errors when running (maybe accidentially) multiple jobs in parallel?

Comment: It does use the static data, yes, loaded into this array 
static String[] XSystemData = new String[4];
It is updated with every iteration.

I did not consider using parameters for updateStockAndPrices(); or instance variables yet. However, it should not run multiple jobs in parallel.

Comment: If it's the API call that's slow then I'd say there are only a few things to do: 1) try to reduce the amount of calls either by batching updates (if the API supports it) or only doing calls that are really necessay (i.e. use a local datastore to check what actually changed). 2) try to parallelize calls if that's possible, 3) check if the API is throttling your requests and if so check if there is a way to get around this (e.g. the API owner might offer some plans with less throttling).

Comment: Don't just assume your code is the reason the process is slow. First gather some metrics so see where the time goes. Add some time-tracking code (start/end times, elapsed times) to the various things it does and see where the time goes. Once you know that you can decide where you need to make improvements.